# reading xml file and parsers in java

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to read a `XML` file using `FileInputStreamReader` class. But, when I try to read large `XML` files, some problems occur. Which java class is more suitable to read large `XML` files and what are the most efficient parsers to parse XML files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that DOM parsing is a good way to parse XML files

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(yourFile);
```

in this way you start the parsing of your XML document, then you can modify the nodes and change what you want to change

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(yourDoc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(yourFile);
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

And this second parte is to save all your changes. The "setOutputPropery" method is not mandatory, it's only used to give to the XML file a nice indent.